# How to use source code from Arduino in ROS?

Tags: ros, ethernet, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am new with ROS and at the moment I am trying to use my sorce from the Arduino robot in ROS.

It is an Arduino robot 4WD that consits these modules : mega2560,Ethernet, motor driver, sensor shield. The functionality of te robot works fine.

I have already tried these hello world example from ros, which worked fine.
Can someone help me out?

I would appreciate for any help.

Thanks ,

Best regards Johan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205085/how-to-use-source-code-from-arduino-in-ros?/) by [Johan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21880/johan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rosserial](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial) can be the link between these two.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2015-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21880/johan/) on 2015-03-22**:
Thx for the advice, It works fine. I worked through some of the tutorials and I realize that I always have to use these commands:

1. `roscore`
2. `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py`
3. `rostopic pub Roll std_msgs/ Empty --once.`

Are there other ways to control the robot?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2015-03-22**:
Trying reading up on ROS to help your understanding.  With rosserial, you can have publishers and subscribers on Arduino.  You can add sub that takes in data lets say `cmd_vel` and publish odometry data such as `encoders`.  Whenever you publish to `cmd_vel`  that data will be used by the Arduino.